# How i push an item to nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an object defined like this. I want to access the role object and push a value into it. I couldn't do it with a map anyway. Any help?

Example: That exactly what i want. I want to map and find role and push some items.  I filter the object if there is the same element i just change its value

```
interface IInitial {
    init: string;
    lang: string;
}

interface IInitialValues {
    role: IInitial[];
    addPrivs: string;
}

const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState<IInitialValues[]>([]);
```

```
initialValues.map((item) => item.role)
             .push({
                 init: "test",
                 lang: "TR",
             })
```

OR

```
initialValues
    .map((item: any) => item === name)
    .filter((item: any) => {
        if (item.lang === activeLang) {
            item.init = value;
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is a mix of things happening here. Undefined variables, mapping to boolean expressions (how is that useful?), using `push`  on an array you didn't keep a reference to, ... lots of issues. Please focus on one particular problem and provide fill input and desired output for it.

Comment: Learn about the [`useState` hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState). You need to set state with `setInitialValues`, you can't set it directly on `initialValues`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use state so you have to return new collection, and not modify the initial collection

```js
///Update the state

setInitialValues(prevValues =>{
  return prevValues.map(item => {
     ///rule to find the item to add roles to
     if (item.addPrivs === 'somethig') {
       ///return cloned object with one more role item
       return {...item, roles:[...item.role, { init: 'newInit',  lang: 'new lang' } ] } 
     } else {
      /// does not match the rule return unmodified item
       return item;
      
     } 
  } )

} )
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Also see immer (https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) which can help this process, especially for deeply nested objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to ask a question. How i can find init value with checking its language. Like:  if the lang equal en i set the its init value to a variable                                                                             
   initialValues
      .map((item: any) => item.role)
      .find((item: any) => item.lang === activeLang).init,

Comment: ```if(item.roles.seom(role => role.lang ===  'something')) ``` this ensures the current item has at least one roll fulfilling the rule

Answer (score 1):

```
initialValues.map((item) => item.role)
             .push(...initialValues, {
                 init: "test",
                 lang: "TR",
             })
```

Comment: Please explain your proposed solution.